# не работает компановщик (setLayout)

Tags: java, swing

Застрял на одном месте, скорее всего не вижу очевидного.

есть приложение, по нажатию кнопок должны меняться панели (работает частично). Я хочу кнопки выставить на ЮГ, а они этого не хотят (располагаются наверху), и я не пойму как их заставить сделать это, посмотрите пожалуйста код, он очень простой, скажите в чем причина.

По факту у меня почему-то получается так, что сразу выходят две кнопки **sweet** и **my button**, **sweet** отображается правильно, как я и хочу, а **my button** где-то наверху, и если нажимать на **sweet** то ничего не происходит (а должна меняться панель), а если нажимать на **my button**, то **sweet** так же уползает наверх, и при этом панели меняются как надо.

```
enum ViewState {
    START_STATE, NEXT_STATE;
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Panel2 extends JPanel {
    public Panel2() {
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,40));
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("sweet");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MyWindowTest.changeState(ViewState.START_STATE);
            }
        });
        panel2.add(button);
        this.add(panel2);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Panel1 extends JPanel {
    public Panel1() {
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,40));
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("my button");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MyWindowTest.changeState(ViewState.NEXT_STATE);
            }
        });
        panel1.add(button);
        this.add(panel1);
    }
}

class MyWindowTest {
    private static ViewState viewState;
    private static JPanel mpanel;
    private static JPanel panel1;
    private static JPanel panel2;
    private static JFrame frame;

    public MyWindowTest() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        mpanel = new JPanel();
        panel1 = new Panel1();
        panel2 = new Panel2();

        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mpanel);

        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout());



        changeState(ViewState.START_STATE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void changeState(ViewState state) {
        viewState = state;
        System.out.println("change state: " + viewState);

        switch (state) {
            case START_STATE:
                mpanel.removeAll();
                mpanel.add(panel1);
                mpanel.revalidate();
                mpanel.repaint();
                break;
            case NEXT_STATE:
                mpanel.removeAll();
                mpanel.add(panel2);
                mpanel.revalidate();
                mpanel.repaint();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("UNKNOWN STATE!");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        MyWindowTest n = new MyWindowTest();

    }

}
```

Если есть предложения по улучшению кода, с радостью выслушаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridLayout всегда сортирует компоненты только в порядке из добавления в контейнер. Вы не можете добавить компоненты в специфичное место, если вам надо поменять их положение, тогда надо добавить пустые компоненты.
Например:

```
form.add(new JPanel());
form.add(new JPanel());
form.add(new JPanel());
form.add(new JPanel());
```

Возможно вы можете использовать GridBagLayout, который может это сделать, но его чуть сложнее использовать.

GridBagLayout поддерживает preferred size компонентов и использование GridBagLayout с GridBagConstraint свойствами:

1. **`gridx, gridy`**
2. **`anchor`**
3. **`weightx, weighty`**
4. **`gridwidth`**
5. **`fill`**

   ```
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
   import java.awt.HeadlessException;
   import java.awt.Insets;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

   /**
    *
    * @author Rashed
    */
   class GridBagLayoutDemo extends JFrame{


       public JLabel createLabel(String txt, int width, int height, Color color)
       {
           JLabel label = new JLabel(txt);
           label.setOpaque(true);
           label.setBackground(color);
           label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
           return label;
       }

       public GridBagLayoutDemo() throws HeadlessException {
           setSize(400,400);
           setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

           JPanel panel = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
           GridBagConstraints labCnst = new GridBagConstraints();

           labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
           labCnst.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
           labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
           labCnst.gridx  = 0;
           labCnst.gridy = 0;
           panel.add(createLabel("play", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);

           // labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
           labCnst.gridx  = 0;
           labCnst.gridy = 2;
           panel.add(createLabel("Status: Ready!", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);

           labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
           labCnst.gridx  = 2;
           labCnst.gridy = 0;
           panel.add(createLabel("-0x", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);

           labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
           labCnst.gridx  = 2;
           labCnst.gridy = 2;
           panel.add(createLabel("score:30", 100, 30, new Color(0x359DBD)), labCnst);


           labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
           labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
           labCnst.gridx  = 2;
           labCnst.gridy = 1;
           labCnst.gridwidth = 1;

           labCnst.weightx = 0.7;
           labCnst.weighty = 0.7;
           panel.add(createLabel("ScoreList", 100, 200, new Color(0xFFAA00)), labCnst);


           labCnst.gridx = 0;
           labCnst.gridy = 1;
           //labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LIN;
           labCnst.gridwidth = 2;

           labCnst.weightx = 0.8;
           labCnst.weighty = 0.8;
           labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           panel.add(createLabel("It is the center", 200, 200, new Color(0xFFD47E)), labCnst);

           //labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;


           add(panel);

       }


       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {
                   new GridBagLayoutDemo().setVisible(true);
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Полностью описание приводить не буду, но можно найти тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707506/how-to-properly-use-gridlayout-to-position-elements-in-a-jframe

Comment: хочу уточнить по первому пункту, мне необходимо создать компонент, а потом добавить туда панель с Button, и после присвоить Layout, правильно?

Comment: @VladZherihov Создаете панель, создаете Grid, потом panel.setlayout(grid), потом создаем button, потом добавляем button на панель. Как-то так. Потом если эта панель является частью contentPanel - добавляете её на contentPanel.